# I want my application run on backgroud service when gps turn on

Tags: java, android, service

I want my application work every time in background when gps turn on 
e.g if closed application , still run
if press back still run
on resume still run
my application get current location and compare it by another lat and long to track client (user)
thanks very much

GPS_Service.class

```
    public class GPS_Service extends Service {

    private LocationListener listener;
    private LocationManager locationManager;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        listener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                Intent i = new Intent("location_update");
                i.putExtra("lat", location.getLatitude());
                i.putExtra("longg", location.getLongitude());
                sendBroadcast(i);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        };

        locationManager = (LocationManager) 
    getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            //noinspection MissingPermission
            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != 
    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) !=     PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    Activity#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for Activity#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }
        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 3000, 0, listener);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if(locationManager != null){
            //noinspection MissingPermission
            locationManager.removeUpdates(listener);
        }
    }
}
```

Activity.class

```
    public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, LocationListener {
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    LocationManager manager;
    Marker marker;
    private Circle mCircle;
    private Marker mMarker;
    Boolean Statein = true;
    Boolean Stateout = true;
    String phone;
    double mLatitude;
    double mLongitude;
    double radiusInMeters;
    private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(broadcastReceiver == null) {
            broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                    Backendless.Data.of(Settings.class).find(new AsyncCallback<List<Settings>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void handleResponse(List<Settings> response) {
                            if (response.size() > 0) {
                                mLatitude = response.get(0).getLat();
                                mLongitude = response.get(0).getLong();
                                radiusInMeters = response.get(0).getRadius();
                            } else {
                                mLatitude = 21.467969;
                                mLongitude = 39.230361;
                                radiusInMeters = 50.0;
                            }

                            phone = getIntent().getStringExtra("phone");

                            float[] distance = new float[2];
                            Location.distanceBetween(intent.getExtras().getDouble("lat"), intent.getExtras().getDouble("longg"),
                                    mLatitude, mLongitude, distance);

                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MapsActivity.this, R.style.MyDialogTheme);
                            builder.setTitle("Location");

                            if (distance[0] > radiusInMeters) {
                                if (Stateout) {
                                    Track track = new Track();
                                    track.setPhone(phone);
                                    track.setState("outside");

                                    Backendless.Persistence.save(track, new AsyncCallback<Track>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void handleResponse(Track response) {
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void handleFault(BackendlessFault fault) {
                                        }
                                    });
                                    //builder.setMessage("خارج المكان ، " + "المسافة: " +  distance[0] + " متر ، " +  "قطر الدائرة: " + mCircle.getRadius() + " متر");
                                    //builder.show();
                                    //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "خارج المكان ، " + "المسافة: " +  distance[0] + " متر ، " +  "قطر الدائرة: " + mCircle.getRadius() + " متر", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    Stateout = false;
                                    Statein = true;
                                }
                            } else {
                                if (Statein) {
                                    Track track = new Track();
                                    track.setPhone(phone);
                                    track.setState("inside");

                                    Backendless.Persistence.save(track, new AsyncCallback<Track>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void handleResponse(Track response) {
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void handleFault(BackendlessFault fault) {
                                        }
                                    });
                                    //builder.setMessage( "داخل المكان ، " + "قطر الدائرة: " + mCircle.getRadius() + " متر");
                                    //builder.show();
                                    //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "داخل المكان ، " + "قطر الدائرة: " + mCircle.getRadius() + " متر", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    Statein = false;
                                    Stateout = true;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void handleFault(BackendlessFault fault) {

                        }
                    });
                }
            };
        }
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver,new IntentFilter("location_update"));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if(broadcastReceiver != null){
            unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        Backendless.Data.of(Settings.class).find(new AsyncCallback<List<Settings>>() {
            @Override
            public void handleResponse(List<Settings> response) {
                if (response.size() > 0) {
                    mLatitude = response.get(0).getLat();
                    mLongitude = response.get(0).getLong();
                    radiusInMeters = response.get(0).getRadius();
                } else {
                    mLatitude = 21.467969;
                    mLongitude = 39.230361;
                    radiusInMeters = 50.0;
                }

                SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
                mapFragment.getMapAsync(MapsActivity.this);
            }

            @Override
            public void handleFault(BackendlessFault fault) {

            }
        });

        if(!runtime_permissions())
            enable_service();
    }\

 private void drawMarkerWithCircle(LatLng position) {
        int strokeColor = 0xffff0000; //red outline
        int shadeColor = 0x44ff0000; //opaque red fill

        CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions().center(position).radius(radiusInMeters).fillColor(shadeColor).strokeColor(strokeColor).strokeWidth(8);
        mCircle = mMap.addCircle(circleOptions);

        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(position);
        mMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Changing map type
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

        // Showing / hiding your current location
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        // Enable / Disable zooming controls
        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

        // Enable / Disable my location button
        mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

        // Enable / Disable Compass icon
        mMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);

        // Enable / Disable Rotate gesture
        mMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);

        // Enable / Disable zooming functionality
        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);


        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(mLatitude, mLongitude), 17));

        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
        options.position(new LatLng(mLatitude, mLongitude));
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(mLatitude, mLongitude);
        drawMarkerWithCircle(latLng);

       /* // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney,10.2f));*/
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }

    private boolean runtime_permissions() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 100);

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == 100) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                enable_service();
            } else {
                runtime_permissions();
            }
        }
    }

    private void enable_service() {
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GPS_Service.class);
        startService(i);
    }
}
```

Manifest

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.galalrabie.trackmap">

    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/.
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".RegisterActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    <service android:name=".GPS_Service"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

it works only when open application and log in but in press back or in close it doesn't work